# Issue Enabling Billing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I have added a credit card and associated the billing account with my project. However, when I hit the Google Vision API with credentials associated with that project, I get the "Project XXXXX has billing disabled. Please enable it." Does anyone know if there are any tricks to get the project to recognize that billing has been added?

Comment: I have the same issue.  Apparently billing information can be cached for a few hours, so I'm planning to just try again tomorrow.

Comment: It started working this morning, so it seems you just have to wait for some hours.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when running the iOS sample application. Make sure you have enabled the Google Cloud Vision API in the API Manager of the Google Cloud Platform console. Once I did this I still had the problem you described. I tried disabling/enabling, which did not help. However, after waiting roughly 24 hours the issue went away and the application is now working.